# UIActivityViewController mixed up header

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiactivityviewcontroller

i present an UIActivityViewController like this:

```
CustomActivityItem* activityItem = [[CustomActivityItem alloc] initWithBody:self.feedItem.link andWithSubject:self.feedItem.title];
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[activityItem] applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:^{

}];
```

Now if i press the share button and choose "Mail", then the subject is not only displayed in the subject field. It is displayed in my Header too. Can i avoid that behavior?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by myself with:

```
[activityViewController setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed) {
    // back to normal color
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Header.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}];
[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:^{
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}];
```